# Adding UILabel in a for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, uilabel

So I tried adding UILabel's in a for loop, and no labels showed up. Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [currentList count]; i++) {
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 3, 5.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
    [label setText:[currentList objectAtIndex:i]];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

That didn't do anything, so I tried adding an NSLog in the for loop, and that worked, though that was just a test to see if the for loop is messed up.

**Update**

Also, how do I add every label away from each other? When I ran this app, they all came piled on each other

Comment: I added it in the .m interface: - @property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *label;

Comment: And no, I did not copy and paste. This is all my coding.

Comment: Which method is this in?

Comment: They'll be added at pixel positions x=0, x=3,6,9... probably not what you want.  Also, probable cause of not seeing the labels is that y=5 might be under a title or status bar.  Try some y>64

Comment: Yah, you're right. Also, how do I add every label away from each other? When I ran this app, they all came piled on each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read a bit about [the view architecture and View Geometry and Coordinate Systems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html).I have no clue as to what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Assuming you would want them to be centered and looking like a list, you could try:

```
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - labelWidth)/2, 64 + heightBetweenLabels*i, labelWidth, labelHeight)];
```

And set **heightBetweenLabels** (which will be this value + 64, and to be more precise , it's the difference between the y coordinate of each label), **labelWidth** and **labelHeight** to your desired values.

Edit:

Let me explain a bit further, see this:

[image]

The top left corner is the origin (x=0, y=0). Positive values of x go right across the screen, while positive values of y go down the screen.Similarly you set the x and y for your label.This helps determine the position of you label relative to it's superview.

If you want the vertical distance to be bigger,or the first label to start from further down , replace **64** with a higher value, as it is not affected by the multiplication.

Comment: This is a good answer, but the only problem is the first UILabel gets the y value of 0 because when i = 0, which will be the first loop around, then we times a number by 0, which gives it a value of 0.

Comment: Anything times 0 will be 0. ex. 64 x 0 = 0

Comment: Whatever I do, the first uilabel does not display

Comment: 64 + somevalue * i will not be 0 for i=0.

Comment: I changed it to a UITextView, and at the first textView, the text does not show until I click on that textview

Comment: Actually I want the y to be the height of the last UILabel + 50. All Labels will have diff heights. Can you please show me how to do that?

Comment: They might not be showing becuase they are overlapping and you have set a grayColor background for every label. First set the background color to clearColor. For you second question , that would be y = previousLabelY (the y of the previous label) + heightOfPreviousLabel + 50.

Comment: The first textViews text is still not showing until I click on it, even when the background's color is clear. The textView itself is showing, not the text

Comment: Do you have an answer?

Comment: Please edit you answer with the new code so i can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599194/first-uitextview-text-is-not-showing/27601585#27601585