# First UITextview text is not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I Inserted multiple UITextviews on a viewController, and the first textViews text is not showing until I double click on it. It then scrolls up, and if I double click on it again, it scrolls back down and I can't see it anymore.

[image] [image]

I then tried to add UITextViews in the actual manually, (not programmatically,) and it did the same thing. The weird thing is that this only happens to one uitextview on the page.

Update

I'll post the code, but I don't think it's relevant because as I said I manually put the UITextViews on another vieController, and it did the same thing, but I'll post it just in case:

```
int heightBetweenLabels = 10;
int labelWidth = 200;
int labelHeight = 1;
int height = 0;
int position = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < [currentListInfo count]; i++) {
    if (height == 0 && position == 0)
    {
        height = 70;
        labelHeight = 50;
    }
    label = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - labelWidth) / 2, height + position + heightBetweenLabels, labelWidth, labelHeight)];

    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    label.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [label setEditable:NO];


    self.label.text = nil;

    label.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
    [self textViewFitToContent:label];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [label setText:[currentListInfo objectAtIndex:i]];

    label.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    height = label.frame.size.height;
    position = label.frame.origin.y;
}
```

Update - 2

This is basically what is happening. I don't know why, but the textView text - "name", is lowered than all the others.

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: the second paragraph seems to be crypted, I am not able to understand it, try to elaborate your problem with some code please

Comment: if autolayout is on,check it is done properly for the added components

Comment: I updated my question and I added some code

Comment: @Mike: You said, you added the textView manually then why are you allocating new textViews ?

Comment: I added them manually in a different viewController (to test it out)

Comment: Just checked it out on another test, and the thing is when I make the textviews height long enough I can see the text. But I don't wanna make it long

Comment: Updated my question again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UIViewController has a automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets property which is YES by default. As UITextView is a ScrollView, the first UITextView you add will have a top inset automatically added to it.

Solution: in your view controller's viewDidLoad or init, set self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to NO.

Comment: Wow you are a genius, thank you so much this just helped me. So ridiculous that this issue exists.

Comment: This is indeed a completely ridiculous and arbitrary issue.. I should just switch to Android development, what the hell is happening to Apple these days? Thank you for your help, though. This worked for me as well

Comment: 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' was deprecated in iOS 11.0 so it could be UIScrollView/UITableView/UICollectionView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 5**
This worked for me:

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of your `UITextView` is embedded in `UIStackView` having `Alignment` and `Distribution` property not set properly.

If `UIStackView` **Alignment** and **Distribution** property are so..

[image]

Changing it to below will probably **fix** this issue..

[image]

Comment: Actually, it was the opposite for me–I had to make the `alignment: Fill` for it to work.